# Android studio, after upgrading gradle version to 7.2 and gradle plugin to 7.1.3 gradle fails to sync

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm currently working on a group project and decided to match my gradle version and plugin to that of my colleagues, but upon upgrading to gradle version to 7.2 and gradle plugin to 7.1.3 my gradle fails to sync.
I am running
Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 3
Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8309675

this is my gradle-wrapper-properties file

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

my build.gradle project file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'
        //classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'//added for maps

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle app file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "easy.tuto.bottomnavigationfragmentdemo"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'//added for maps
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

}
```

Here is a screenshot of my error
[image: Error message in Android studio]